# Creating apps that embed into gmail

Tags: gmail

I can't seem to find the developer center where it tells you how to create apps that embed into gmail.

BTW, when you embed an app into gmail, can you read users emails somehow?  Isn't this a privacy issue or you just have to trust the app developer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept is called [Gmail contextual gadgets](https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets) and is generally available now.

<del>[It's not yet publicly available as of August, 2010.](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2010/03/integrating-with-google-apps-using.html)</del>

Comment: Rapportive is a browser plugin, not a Gmail gadget.  Since you would be running Rapportive in the context of your local machine, it would have all kinds of access to whatever was currently displayed in your browser.  As I understand it, Gmail contextual gadgets will be written by third parties but served within the Gmail app by Google themselves.